# Is it possible to perform a XSS attack using jQuery's .attr("src", value) method for <img> tags?

Tags: jquery, html, xss

Given is the following html fragment, which is statically typed in an html file:

```
<img src="https://www.google.com/img.png" id="img001" alt="">
```

Please consider, that the attribute value of `src` is quoted. Is it possible to perform a XSS attack when the attacker can provide an arbitrary value for the variable `unsafe_string` in the following context:

```
$('#img001').attr("src", unsafe_string);
```

My question is: Is it possible to inject and execute malicious code? The attacker has only control of `unsafe_string` and nothing else.

In the past, with older (outdated) browsers, there have been attacks like

```
<img src="javascript:alert('XSS');">
```

which are not possible any more in modern browsers, as far as I have found out (see for example: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Script_in_IMG_tags and https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_Filter_Evasion_Cheat_Sheet#INPUT_image). I am interested in attacks with modern (up-to-date) browsers.

Comment: It's hard to prove a negative, and I'm also not very confident, but I think the answer is: no, this is not possible. I would have liked it to be, would have helped with this CTF challenge we're solving :)